# IOS6 Prevent/Limit zooming in a MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit

Is there a way to prevent/limit the zooming. I want to allow the user to zoom to my set fixed limits.
The option to do with:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Is disgusting because first you zoom in and when you are done it automatically zooms out.
The goal is to stop zooming when the user reach the zoomlimit, even if he proceed with the gesture.

To derive from MKMapView in iOS6 is not purposeful because there no scrollView methods to override :(

Any other ideas?

Comment: With 100+ votes and an accepted answer this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830516/prevent-scrolling-in-a-mkmapview-also-when-zooming

Comment: @Craig: there was a bounty worthing 100 points, but not 100+ votes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:myCoord zoomLevel:13 animated:YES];
```