# How to stop scrolling in mkmapview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm using a `MKMapView` in my application and use `mapView.scrollEnabled=NO;` but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 282, 209)];
mapView.delegate=self;
mapView.scrollEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have used `YES` instead of `NO` in your code. Please use `NO` as below.

```
mapView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Swift

```
mapView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to set

```
mapView.scrollEnabled=NO;
```

or set

```
mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

but it does not allow you to zoom in or out and other things.
click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830516/prevent-scrolling-in-a-mkmapview-also-when-zooming) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `userInteractionEnabled` property of `MKMapView` to `NO`.

```
mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```